# Youtube live broadcast invalid Embed Setting

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

When creating a live broadcast through api I need to insert it in my web page, but when passing the attribute `"enableEmbed": true`, I get the following error:

> Embed setting was invalid

If I do not pass the embed attribute, it does not allow me to view the stream on my website.
How can I do it through api to see the broadcast on my website?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I couldn't set enableEmbed to true.

So I opened an issue on: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158696654
I received the answer that they tried and they couldn't reproduce the error.
So I tried again with another account, my own account, and it worked.

The problem is that account is too new, if you use an old account, you will probably be able to set it true.

To confirm, login in with the account you are using and access the link: https://www.youtube.com/features
Confirm that [Embed live streams] is Enabled.

Comment: Do you know how long it takes for such a new account to set embed = true?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. I tried searching for that, but I could not find it. I guess it's about trust, your account must be verified and trustable.